# DRY principal in django for needing to use the same query in every function

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a question. I have a django project where I inherit a navigation bar in all my rendered html views. I want to pass a variable that records how many of certain instance exisits within my DB.
Okay so this is extremely simple if I write a query in every single function that renders an html page that {%include 'partials/navbar.html'%}, and every function does because I extend my index file which includes my navbar
So like I said it super simple to write a query within every single function and then pass this value in the context. But is there a way that is less tedious almost like an injector in angular?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h67c.png)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're looking to have a piece of context in each template without explicitly passing that context to each view every time? If so, this sounds like a job for a `context processor`.

Comment: Yes exactly that! Could you kindly point to an example of a context processor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A context processor makes a piece of context available in every template, without having to manually pass it into the context of each view.

Firstly, you need to create your context processor. Create a `context_processors.py` inside the directory of one of your apps. For example, if you have an app called `myapp`, the directory should look like this (where `...` represents the other files/folders inside of that app):

```
myapp/
    ...
    context_processors.py
```

In that newly create file, add your piece of context:

```py
def my_objects(request):
    return {'all_my_objects': MyObject.objects.all()}
```

In your project's `settings.py`, you have a `TEMPLATES` variable. You need to add the full dotted path to the method of your context processor:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'myapp.context_processors.my_objects', # <--- here
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

You can then use this like any other context you pass into your templates.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Create a file inside in your application folder: (custom_context_processor.py)
```

2 Inside (custom_context_processor.py)

`def subject_renderer(request): return{ "key": Example.objects.all()`

3. In setings.py

`'OPTIONS':context_processors:[All the other functions.... yourappname_context_processor.subject_renderer ]`

4. In any html template call your key value pair '{{key}}'